# CSS - Firefox - Getting Child elements to sit inside the parent element

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

All,

Here is the code.

```
#feature_tabs_indicators {
display: block;
height: 14.5px;
background-color: rgb(244,1,87);
}
#feature_tabs_indicators ul {
    display: block;
    height: 14.5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    #feature_tabs_indicators ul li {
        display: inline;
        width: auto;
        height: 14.5px;
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: rgb(34,61,166);
        padding: 0 5px;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

An now the HTML:

```
<div id="feature_tabs_indicators">
        <ul>
            <li id="ind_bt" class="c_ind">.</li>
            <li id="ind_st" class="c_ind">.</li>
            <li id="ind_lc" class="c_ind">.</li>
            <li id="ind_rb" class="c_ind">.</li>
            <li id="ind_lg" class="c_ind">.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[**Jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/mHAs4/)

Problem:
When I run the code in Chrome, IE9, all looks well, i.e. the blue squares in the middle are sitting on the red line (parent). However, when I run this in Firefox, their appears a sit slightly below the parent. You can see the thin red line peeking out on top of the blue squares.

Why is this and how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check inline to inline-block on your LI.

```
 #feature_tabs_indicators ul li {
            display: inline-block;
...
}
```

Comment: Diodeus, spot on. Care to explain why or reference please.

Comment: Inline items cannot take a height value, only block items can. Also, keep in mind, there is not such thing as a HALF PIXEL 14.5 is meaningless. It will get truncated to 14.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, that clarifies it a lot.

Comment: @Diodeus Actually, it's only WebKit that will truncate 14.5 to 14.  Both Gecko and Trident do subpixel positioning and rendering (with antialiasing as needed).  This matters especially on high-dpi devices like phones, where a single CSS pixel maps to multiple device pixels.

Answer (score 1):

@salman Khan; give `inline-block` to your `#feature_tabs_indicators ul li` .

The reason why `li's` not come inside the parent because  `inline` element never take vertical `margin & padding`. That's why `parent` take the `height` of the text only.

check this article http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/

Comment: Thank you for the reference Sandeep. Much appreciated.